# Repeating node multiple times based on the input structure

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

I have one requirement, I am new to XSLT language so I am looking for your help for my below requirement.

Below is the input xml payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <ns0:sendfile xmlns:ns0="namepsace here">
<Delivery>
   <IssueDateTime>2016-05-24T09:25:19z</IssueDateTime> 
 <Item>
  <order>
   <orderChar>
     <orderName /> 
     <orderVal /> 
   </orderChar>
   <orderInfo>
    <Product /> 
     <Batch /> 
       <Qty /> 
      <UOM /> 
  </orderInfo>
  </order>
 </Item>
</Delivery>
```

so in the file **orderchar** node and **orderInfo** node will repeat multiple times based on that in receiver structure 2 nodes should repeat. for example

orderchar segment is repeating 20 times, in receiver also E1ADRM segment should repeat same number of times.
order info also same case in receiver E1DRM segment should repeat same number of times.In case any of the node will not come in receiver also the segment should not populate.

I think we can do this some value of select with that syntax. could you please help me on this.

I tried with below code and able to generate the node.  but when repeated nodes are coming the repeated receiver nodes are not populating.

```
<ns0:if test="count(./order/orderChar)!=0">
 <E1EDL12 SEGMENT="1">
<ATNAM>
<ns0:value-of select="./orderChar/orderName"/>
 </ATNAM>
<ATWRT>
<ns0:value-of select="./orderChar/orderName"/>
</ATWRT>
</E1EDL12>
```

above code tried for only for one segment.could you please suggest what modification I have to do to populate multiple times.

Regards,
Janardhan

Comment: Can you show a slightly more meaningful input XML sample (one which actually has some repeated nodes, and has some data in). You should also show the expected output. Additionally, can you show a bit more of the current XSLT you are using. Thank you.

Comment: A couple of remarks and questions:
1. You used a number of symbols which you failed to explain (e.g. E1ADRM and E1DRM). What is their meaning?
2. You wrote _in receiver_ and this is also unclear.
3. I have some doubts about the phrase _should repeat same number of times_. Which things should occur the same number of times?
To sum up: Can you describe the whole thing in a more understandable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really haven't made your requirement very clear, but my guess would be that you want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="orderChar">
  <ATNAM>
    <xsl:value-of select="orderName"/>
  </ATNAM>
  <ATWRT>
    <xsl:value-of select="./orderChar/orderName"/>
  </ATWRT>
</xsl:for-each>
```